# How to disable 'Use JAI ImageRead (deferred loading)' on an Image Mosaic layer?

Tags: raster, geoserver, web-mapping, ubuntu

I'm running GeoServer from the binary files on Ubuntu 19.10. I'm trying to optimise Image Mosaic layers for speedy display via WMS. To do this I would like to enable Multithreaded granule loading (disable JAI ImageRead to use it), however this requires Use JAI ImageRead to be set to off. The tick box beside this option on the layer settings page is greyed out and cannot be unchecked. How can I set this option to off?

````
Locks   0   
Free locks
Connections     0   
Memory Usage    343 MB / 672 MB     
Free memory
JVM Version     Private Build: 1.8.0_252 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM)     
Java Rendering Engine   sun.java2d.pisces.PiscesRenderingEngine     
Available Fonts     GeoServer can access 314 different fonts. Full list of available fonts  
Native JAI  true    
Native JAI ImageIO  true    
JAI Maximum Memory  336 MB  
JAI Memory Usage    5 MB    
Free memory
JAI Memory Threshold    75%     
Number of JAI Tile Threads  7   
JAI Tile Thread Priority    5   
ThreadPoolExecutor Core Pool Size   5   
ThreadPoolExecutor Max Pool Size    10  
ThreadPoolExecutor Keep Alive Time (ms)     30000   
Update Sequence     588```
````

Comment: Can you turn it on and off for the `nurc:mosaic` layer? if so then it is something to do with your layer set up, if not it is something to do with your GS setup. It works fine for me.

Comment: Also switching to the marlin renderer will be an easy win + properly preparing the mosaic granules

Comment: I've just done a fresh install of GeoServer using the stable binaries to /usr/share/geoserver. Still cannot uncheck that box on the nurc:mosaic layer.

Comment: Could it be a permissions issue? — I'm running GS on a 'locked down' company machine to which I have sudo access.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but the resolution came down to an old version of Firefox (72.0).  Worked in Chrome (85.0) and IE-11, so will be switching browsers due to inability to upgrade FF.